# How do I show an image from the latest post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress, I want to show the 2 latest posts along with the post thumbnail for just the first post.

I have been playing around with the code below, but an image always ends up being shown for the first post as well as the second, when I only want to show an image for the first.

```
<?php 
$cat_args = array(
'orderby' => 'name',
'order' => 'ASC',
'child_of' => 0
);


 $post_args = array(
  'numberposts' => 2,
  'category' => $category->term_id 
);

$posts = get_posts($post_args);

foreach($posts as $post) {
?>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_post_thumbnail('blog_post_image'); ?>
<?php 
} 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're sort of missing any condition that would allow you to selectively display the image.

```
<?php
foreach($posts as $key=>$post) {
    the_title();

    if (0 == $key) {
        the_post_thumbnail('blog_post_image');
    }
}
```

Assuming `$posts` is a 0-based enumerated array. Notice the addition of `$key` to the `foreach`, as well as the `if` before printing the thumbnail

Comment: I'm not very good with PHP, where would I slot this in the code above?

Comment: @AdamScott Replace your existing `foreach` loop

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $loop = 1; ?> 
<?php foreach($posts as $post): ?> 
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php if($loop == 1): ?>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('blog_post_image'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php $loop++; endforeach; ?>
```